# Break line using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to break my string using javascript which is fetching some data from a php file using ajax. The php is returning the correct data, however the javascript doesn't treat a `<br>` tag properly. This is my ajax code and i am using it to replace the current text in that `span`.

```
type: "post", url: "some_php.php", data: "name="+name,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#someDiv').text(data);
    }
```

Using `console.log(data)` i get the output as:

```
Some<br>Address<br>to<br>be<br>borken
```

No i want it to output as

```
Some
Address
to
be
broken
```

Comment: do you even know about the <address> tag ??

Comment: Yes, thats what i am using inside the div!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

```
 $('#someDiv').html(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong jQuery function:

```
$('#someDiv').html(data);
```

From [jQuery's text() function](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> .text( textString ) Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text.

From [jQuery's html() function](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

> .html( htmlString ) Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(data.split('<br>').join('\n'));
```

You can use the previous method to replace all `<br>`s with newlines.

If you want to have one console entry for each line, use:

```
console.log.apply(console, data.split('<br>'));
```

Comment: Works fine for the `console.log` but not for the changing text in the span :S

Comment: @Namit Then use `.html()`, which will also deal with HTML entities.